# Spring Boot Test does not detect static nested @Named component in test class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-test

Following is my class code for test class.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { SpringBootApp.class }, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class OuterBeanTest {

    @Inject
    InnerBeanTest innerBean;

    @Test
    public void test() {
         assertThat(this.innerBean.print()).isEqualTo("print");
    }

    @Named
    static class InnerBeanTest {

        String print(){
             return "print";
        }
    };
}
```

But injection of static class into the test instance throws an error about `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'innerBean'; expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.`

How can I inject it into the test instance?

**EDIT**

`OuterBeanTest.java` is in `com.general` package in `src/test/java`, whereas Spring Boot Application is in `com` package in `src/main/java`

`SpringBootApp.java`

```
package com;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

NOTE: The same worked `Spring-4.2.8` but now I have upgraded to `Spring-4.3.7` and it stopped working.

Comment: 'Inner static' is a contradiction in terms. See JLS #8.1.3. This is a static class.

Comment: @EJP was being explicit, I know the difference.

Comment: We are missing some pertinent information: What package does `OuterBeanTest` reside in? What package does `SpringBootApp` reside in? And what annotations are present on `SpringBootApp`?

Comment: `OuterBeanTest` is not a _bean_: it is a test class. I am therefore going to (attempt to) edit the title.

Comment: What is `TestBean`?

Comment: @SamBrannen it was a  typo fixed it

Comment: Are you by any chance using `@TestConfiguration` anywhere? If so, that is perhaps the source of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The testing support in Spring Boot 1.4 no longer detects static nested components within test classes automatically. This is due to the use of the `org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.TestTypeExcludeFilter` behind the scenes.

Thus, you have two options.

1. Move `InnerBeanTest` to a top-level class, or...
2. Annotate `OuterBeanTest` with `@Import(OuterBeanTest.InnerBeanTest.class)`.

Regards,

Sam